# Cannot get the "+" sign to display

Tags: php, special-characters

I have this value in a mysql database: "A+" it's the name of a magazine.
I can see it sitting in the database, however i cannot manage to have it display via php.
When i fetch the sql data, it outputs

"A "

I tried utfencode() utfdecode() htmlentities() ... to no avail. I fail to diagnose the problem.
In case it matters, i fetch this data via ajax (jquery load() function)

UPDATE:

It turns out the + sign is removed while parsing the data through a regular expression. can't seem to find a fix for that either. preg_quote() is of no use.

Comment: If you monitor the response data in Firebug, does the "+" come through?  That would narrow down the scope of the problem.

Comment: no, in firebug, the + does not show through either.

I'm not sure what code to post. Basically, just doing in php

echo "A+"; in php echoes "A "

Comment: note that i can see the + if i urlencode() it via php. But i don't want to systematically urlencode content that is intended for humans

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is possible that jquery is interpreting it as the url encoded '+' sign, which can be interpreted as a space.  Post some code and I'm sure somebody can give you a full answer.

Comment: following your suggestions, i tried just outputting directly "A+" by hardcoding it in the php output string. problem remains. htmlentities did not help either. only "urlencode()" makes the + appear ! now, that's a problem: i don't want to urlencode text that should be human-readable. lost i am...

Comment: which PHP output string?  The one that produces the string in the ajax call?  or directly on an otherwise empty PHP script page?

Comment: a simple string, like: 
echo "publisher name: A+<br/>published in 1999";

Comment: @jonstjohn: I can almost guarantee that's the problem, espcially considering pixeline's urlencode() reply.

Comment: do you mean that my lengthy text that contains the "+" sign is sent back via a GET request? sounds weird. i thought there was a 255 character limit.

Answer (score 1):

The `+` character is interpreted as space when the data is declared as [`application/x-www-form-urlencoded`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.1):

> This is the default content type. Forms submitted with this content type must be encoded as follows:
>
> 1. Control names and values are escaped. **Space characters are replaced by '`+`'**, and then reserved characters are escaped as described in [RFC1738], section 2.2: Non-alphanumeric characters are replaced by '`%HH`', a percent sign and two hexadecimal digits representing the ASCII code of the character. Line breaks are represented as "CR LF" pairs (i.e., '`%0D%0A`').
> 2. The control names/values are listed in the order they appear in the document. The name is separated from the value by '`=`' and name/value pairs are separated from each other by '`&`'.

So you have to encode it properly. In JavaScript, use the `encodeURIComponent` function if you want to use `+` character in an URI:

```
"http://www.example.com/?q=" + encodeURIComponent("A+")
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you pass it as an javascript parameter without [urlencode()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php)'ing it?

Comment: no, i don't pass it. It is sitting in the fetched html string.

Answer (score 0):

Well, since the only way to make it work is to do

```
echo urlencode("this is the A+ text");
```

It works and does not seem to damage the rest of the text, but i don't understand the rationale behind this. Anyway, thanks to all of those who tried to help.

Answer (score -1):

You can add a escape character before the \ and see how that works. If not convert the field data using [htmlentities](http://ca.php.net/htmlentities)

Comment: following your suggestions, i tried just outputting directly "A+" by hardcoding it in the php output string. problem remains.
htmlentities did not help either.

only "urlencode()" makes the + appear ! now, that's a problem: i don't want to urlencode text that should be human-readable. lost i am...